# curvilinear interpolation of spatial data based on exact time or distance boundaries

Tags: r, datetime, interpolation, spatial

I have some spatial tracking data and would like to use a form of curvilinear interpolation based on a specified time interval between two points (i.e. adding interpolated coordinates to a track section at exact time boundaries). I am looking for a method in R that uses something like bézier curves or hermite polynomials.

My data is currently in approximate 1-hour intervals and I would like to interpolate to 10-minute intervals (and to set distance intervals) using a curvilinear interpolation method. Example data is below (latitude/longitude are presented in both geographical format and UTM projected coordinate format):

```
structure(list(datetime = c("01/06/2012 09:12", "01/06/2012 10:13", 
"01/06/2012 11:10", "01/06/2012 12:08", "01/06/2012 13:08", "01/06/2012 14:07", 
"01/06/2012 15:08", "01/06/2012 16:07", "01/06/2012 17:06", "01/06/2012 18:09", 
"01/06/2012 19:09"), latitude = c(52.535242, 52.503073, 52.500524, 
52.483297, 52.473904, 52.465271, 52.456518, 52.456239, 52.455416, 
52.459805, 52.454516), longitude = c(3.518238, 3.554792, 3.543656, 
3.555478, 3.55516, 3.545761, 3.534289, 3.517849, 3.498159, 3.483334, 
3.45681), long_meters = c(535151.3255, 537658.2061, 536904.4563, 
537721.688, 537708.1226, 537076.9734, 536304.8134, 535187.9496, 
533850.6498, 532840.0096, 531041.5721), lat_meters = c(5820698.249, 
5817138.477, 5816849.2, 5814939.133, 5813894.178, 5812929.062, 
5811949.637, 5811910.471, 5811809.523, 5812290.872, 5811690.849
)), .Names = c("datetime", "latitude", "longitude", "long_meters", 
"lat_meters"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

I would like to end up with a coordinate for every 10-minute period (or for every nth distance). Each interpolated coordinate must have a matching datetime.

While answers to questions such as [Interpolation in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885155/interpolation-in-r) are helpful, they do not give me exactly what I want. I would rather not use cubic splines, as can be done with `spline()`.

A comment on the following post ([Interpolating a path/curve within R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356997/interpolating-a-path-curve-within-r)) suggests that functions exist in R that might be able to do this. I am aware that linear interpolation can be performed in a similar way in the `adehabitatLT` package using `redisltraj()` or in the `trip` package, but I am yet to find a curvilinear equivalent.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean Tremblay et al. (2006) specifically? (http://jeb.biologists.org/content/209/1/128.short) Wouldn't great circle interpolation be enough, or have you considered whether it ought to be loxodromic? We could figure out or find how to do this, I just think it's a bit unnecessary. Can you expand on how basic interpolation doesn't do what you want? (Frankly I think that map projections are far more important than these rather nice looking smooth methods).

Comment: @ Michael thanks for your response. Yes, I have been reading Tremblay's paper which seems to suggest that curvilinear interpolation methods can present a more realistic way of interpolating tracking data. However, maybe linear methods are still very valid. I am relatively new to this! Do the linear interpolation methods use great circle distance or is there an alternative function that can perform great circle interpolation? I believe that with 'redisltraj' coordinates need to be in projected cartesian format.

Comment: Check out library(geosphere);vignette("geosphere") and sections "Points on great circles" and "Rhumb lines". I'll work on updating interpequal in the trip package to use that (long overdue).